# How to list all opened indices that have at least one document?

Tags: elasticsearch, get, settings

I want to get all opened indices in Elasticsearch5.1 that have at least one document in this index.
I can get all opened indices through this:

`es.indices.get_settings(index=index_prefix + '*', params={'expand_wildcards': 'open'})`

but most of the indices are an empty document. How to filter the empty indices?

Comment: for example: I get the indices:[my_index-2017.11.22, my_index-2017.11.21...] but only my_index-2017.11.*  have some doc under each index, how to filter them?